# Time/Space complexity of adjacency matrix and adjacency list

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am reading "Algorithms Design" By Eva Tardos and in chapter 3 it is mentioned that adjacency matrix has the complexity of `O(n^2)` while adjacency list has `O(m+n)` where m is the total number of edges and n is the total number of nodes. It says that in-case of adjacency list we will need only lists of size m for each node.

Won't we end up with something similar to matrix in case of adjacency list as we have lists,which are also 1D arrays. So basically it is `O(m*n)` according to me. Please guide me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An adjacency **matrix** keeps a value (1/0) for every pair of nodes, whether the edge exists or not, so it requires `n*n` space.

An adjacency **list** only contains existing edges, so its length is at most the number of edges (or the number of nodes in case there are fewer edges than nodes).

> It says that in-case of adjacency list we will need only lists of size
>   m for each node.

I think you misunderstood that part. An adjacency list *does not* hold a list of size `m` for *every* node, since `m` is the number of edges overall.

In a fully connected graph, there is an edge between every pair of nodes so both adjacency list and matrix will require `n*n` of space, but for every other case - an adjacency list will be smaller.

Comment: All this is only about how much space the data structures used to represent the graph need (which is what Rajat seems to ask for). We often also want to be able to perform certain operations on the graph (e.g. edge insertion/deleten/existence check), and the two structures offer different time complexities for some of them, which is something to keep in mind.

Comment: @yurib, this is a great response.  Thanks!

Comment: Should "fully connected graph" actually be "complete graph" in this answer?

Comment: @MarkusAmaltheaMagnuson Yes, a graph with all edges present...